# WSO2 Api manager request execution problems

Tags: wso2

So I've deployed my WSO2 APIM instance to an Azure VM, changed the hostname to be the same as the VM, also the gateway.
I'm then having problems during requests execution, I'm getting [CORS Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPaIT.png)

Comment: If you are using a self signed certificate then you need to accept the certificate in the browser. Step 3 in here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/api-manager-quick-start-guide/#step-3-invoke-the-api

Comment: The thing is if I try to access the :8243 port I get that my connection is refused, even though I already opened the port in Azure portal config and allowed it in the firewall, note that I'm working with a deployed version .

Comment: How do I mark this as solved ?

Comment: What is the gateway port exposed? Maybe it is 443. Just copy/paste the url on the browser that you get from the try out console. And accept the certificate. If this is not the case you can check the network tab(Browser developer console). It has some information

Comment: I exposed the 8243 during the docker run command and it just worked, thank you.